# Optional type usage in Single Table Inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, single-table-inheritance

i have an asset class which have type, name, label etc.

Asset types are: avatar, image, video, summary etc.

I want to have Video < Asset type only for type = 'video', but for all other types - Asset should be used.

If i use self.inheritance_column = 'type' - it fails, because cant find Avatar class.
Is there any approach how to map all types to Asset class except video?

Thanks,
Kirill Salykin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That won't work. You're either doing STI with those types or you aren't.

The way to do it is use `type` as your STI column, and something like `asset_type` as your categorization column. Then only video gets the `type` column, all other assets use the `asset_type` column to tell what's what.

Comment: I see, maybe there any way to monkey patch class name resolving routin or some callback exists?

Comment: You're going to create far more headaches than are worth it. If you want two different behaviors just use two different column names :)